# Disable Days in jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date

I have two date pickers.

Start Date and End date.

i am trying to disable days in "End date" date picker which are below the selected date in start date.

i tried following code :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" ,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
    }
    });
    });
    $(function() {

    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" ,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,onSelect: function (selected) {

    }
    });

    });
```

yes the dates are disabling only when start date selected.

after saving(page gets reloaded), previously disabled dates are now enabled.

now user can select date before start date  in end date .

thank you!

Comment: You never set a `minDate` option when initialising `#datepicker2` so what do you expect? You just need to do that as part of the initialisation, using the currently selected date for `#datepicker1`.

Comment: thank u , it worked after initializing  minDate in datepicker 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `onClose` instead of `onSelect` like

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" ,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/cal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLUjZ/)

Comment: problem is still there, after saving details, dates are enabling again.

Comment: Then initially disable the second datepicker and enable only when the first was selected

Comment: it worked , i set minDate in #datepicker2 and disabled out side on select, thank you!!